# Don't work `ConstraintLayout` Gone Visibility

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView Adapter and in it, I have the bottom code:

```
 holder.HeaderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (holder.DetailLayout.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                        holder.DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        holder.DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But my result is the bottom pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the whole classes code

Comment: call notifyItemChanged or nofityDatasetChanged after view has changed to publish your changes
داداش اون ایندکس آیتمی که تغییر دادی رو نوتیفای کن

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call 
[notifyItemChanged(indexOfChange)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyitemchanged_1) for the index you are changing, or [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifydatasetchanged)

first option is better for performance

Comment: I changed my code to :   holder.DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.HeaderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (holder.DetailLayout.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                        holder.DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                    } else {
                        holder.DetailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
                    }
                }
            });